# How to set trigger in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Post model having fields of `id`, `no_o_likes`, `no_of_comments` etc.
and User model having fields `id`, `name` etc.

And another model is LikePost having `user_id` and `post_id`.

Now I want if user like the post then one entry will be in LikePost model with `user_id` and `post_d` after that a trigger should be fire to increment the `no_of_likes` by 1.

So please suggest how can i set the trigger in laravel to do this?

Comment: What did you try so far, sir?

Comment: This is solveable, but in general you need to provide a code example